# How to save the state of a checkbox

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, checkbox

How to save the state of a checkbox in Visual studio ultimate 2012 using C#. That is  even after the app is terminated when I reopen again the last viewed state should be visible? what to do? Could u please help me with the code.

Thanks in advance.....

J.Visali

Comment: Do you mean a checkbox in a wpf application or something else?

Comment: @Despertar - the question title says windows 8 metro app

Comment: its check box in a windows 8 metro app

Answer (score 4):

Here you should find all you need: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For most Windows 8 Store apps, data can largely be classified under two categories:

1. App Data – settings, files, cache, session state, custom lists etc.
2. User Data – documents, credentials, photos, music etc.

This article [Data Persistence & Application Life-Cycle Management](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-8-Apps-The-8-Must-Know-Tricks-Day-6.aspx) should help you understand what type of persistence do you need.
Data can be persisted, as *Application Settings* in key-value pairs, but can also be saved as *Application Files*, which is usually stored in the sandboxed file system access that Apps have.

As a quick example you should have:

```
   // Reference to Local Application Settings.
   Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings; 
   // Reference to Roaming Application Settings.
   Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;  
   // Persisting simple Application Settings.
   localSettings.Values["myOption1"] = myBox1.isChecked;
   roamingSettings.Values["myOption2"] = myBox2.isChecked;

   // Reading settings back.
   var mySavedOption1 = (bool)(localSettings.Values["myOption1"]);
   var mySavedOption2 = (bool)(roamingSettings.Values["myOption2"]);
```

**Edit**

Tested example that works:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        // Reference to Local Application Settings.
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        // Reading settings back.
        object mySavedOption1;
        localSettings.Values.TryGetValue("myOption1Key", out mySavedOption1);
        if (mySavedOption1 != null)
            myOption1.IsChecked = (bool)mySavedOption1;
    }

    private void myOption1_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Reference to Local Application Settings.
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        // Persisting simple Application Settings.
        localSettings.Values["myOption1Key"] = myOption1.IsChecked;

    }
```

In xaml:`<CheckBox x:Name="myOption1" Grid.Row="1" Checked="myOption1_Checked_1" Unchecked="myOption1_Checked_1"/>`

Comment: thanks a lot..... but its not working for me....:( can you please refine it again.........

Comment: thanks u very much @ana 01 this one really worked well for me.....:) thanks a ton........

Comment: this is working very good for only one check box but this is not saving multiple Check Boxes..... what to do in order to save the state of multiple Check boxes..... thanks in advance.....

Comment: thanks a lot........ it worked for multiple check boxes too..... u r awesome....... thank you very much....... thanks a ton.....:)

Comment: how many check boxes do you have? are they related? if not, maybe storing them under different key would help, something like: key "myCheck1Key" , "myCheck2Key". Or maybe a dictionary stored at a specific key,like "allMyOptionsKey", with all options do you need,although I'm not sure it helps that much. But if you choose to have multiple keys, you should have multiple Checked/Unchecked handlers, or One handler that properly identifies the event source and finds the appropriate key. If you use only one key for all your Ckecks, it's wrong.

Comment: i am having around 25 checkboxes and after doing these modifications this helped a lot and they worked well........... thanks a ton........ :).......it worked well

Comment: could you please help me how to get the near by geographical locations like hotels, malls, etc into a text box in the app.                            thanks in advance........

Comment: sorry, I'm afraid I can't help you with that. You could address  another question, and mark the appropriate answer to this one.

Comment: thanks again inn i will post the answer after i am done with it.......u r really awesome ana 01..... you helped me a lot in this app....... thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use the local storage provided by the app:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["CheckboxState"] = "checked";
```

Then you can restore using the same `localSettings` by extracting the state from values.

Comment: Its working perfectly..... could you please help me in restoring the state too.Thanks a ton.......

Answer (score 1):

apps setting is the best way to store the app data... the best solution for the
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings